# Elevation profile

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, openstreetmap

I'm working on a App and i will show an elevation profile of route. I need also to show my current position on the elevation profile.

All the data (Altitude, Route points) will be on a gpx file, which could be made on a pc and uploaded to the phone.

I have been googling for a while and i found an API from google (Google Elevation API). Unfortunately it's a web service and therefore i would need a network connection, something i don't won't.
The other possibility is to crate a XY diagramm using aChartEngine or tools provided by Android itself.

Do anyone know other frameworks or methods to draw an elevation profile ?

PS: I use OpenStreetMap, due to the offline maps

Comment: You can build charts from GPX with http://www.highcharts.com/